# @font-face doesn't loading font

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

I have this css:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'test';
src: url(test.woff2) format('woff2'),
     url(test.woff) format('woff'),
     url(test.ttf) format('truetype');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}

body {
font-family: 'test';
font-size: 14px;
}
```

And it doesn't renders custom font. I'm using chrome so I able to see resources, and there is no font loaded by my site.

Edit: now I'm able to load font, but it doesn't seems to be used

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem was that my font wasn't containing letters of my language